# Pandas Groupby mean and first of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
My Pandas df is like following and want to apply groupby and then want to calculate the average and first of many columns

index col1   col2   col3   col4   col5  col6
  0     a      c      1      2      f    5
  1     a      c      1      2      f    7
  2     a      d      1      2      g    9
  3     b      d      6      2      g    4
  4     b      e      1      2      g    8
  5     b      e      1      2      g    2
```

something like this I tried

```
df.groupby(['col1','col5').agg({['col6','col3']:'mean',['col4','col2']:'first'})
```

expecting output

```
col1  col5   col6  col3  col4  col2
  a     f     6     1     2     c
  a     g     9     1     2     d
  b     g     4     3     2     e
```

but it seems, list is not an option here, in my real dataset I have 100 of columns of different nature so I cant pass them individually. Any thoughts on passing them as list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have lists depending on the aggregation, you can do:

```
l_mean = ['col6','col3']
l_first = ['col4','col2']
df.groupby(['col1','col5']).agg({**{col:'mean' for col in l_mean},
                                 **{col:'first' for col in l_first}})
```

the notation `**{}` is for unpacking dictionary, doing `{**{}, **{}}` create one dictionary from 2 dictionaries (it could be ore than two), it is like union of dictionaries. And doing `{col:'mean' for col in l_mean}` create a dictionary with each `col` of the list as a key and `'mean'` as value, it is dictionary comprehension.

Or using `concat`:

```
gr = df.groupby(['col1','col5'])
pd.concat([gr[l_mean].mean(), 
           gr[l_first].first()], 
          axis=1)
```

and `reset_index` after to get the expected output

Comment: Nice answer.  You might include an explanation of `**{col:'mean' for col in l_mean}`.  I'm guess a lot of people won't really grock it.  /shrug

Comment: Yes pls, It will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
(
    df.groupby(['col1','col5'])
    .agg(col6=('col6', 'mean'),
        col3=('col3', 'mean'),
        col4=('col4', 'first'),
        col2=('col2', 'first'))
)
```

Comment: It will pass columns one at a time, in my real dataset I have 100s of columns, cant pass like this

Answer (score 0):

this is an extension of @Ben.T's solution, just wrapping it in a function and passing it via the [pipe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#piping-function-calls) method :

```
#set the list1, list2 
def fil(grp,list1,list2):
    A = grp.mean().filter(list1)
    B = grp.first().filter(list2)
    C = A.join(B)
    return C

grp1 = ['col6','col3']
grp2 = ['col4','col2']
m = df.groupby(['col1','col5']).pipe(fil,grp1,grp2)
m
```